# Extraneous solutions where they come from?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I was doing some homework on logarithmic equations, and when I check my solutions on wolfram alpha I get that some aren't. So I'm interested in where do those extraneous equations come from?

Comment: Can you give an actual example or two of what you are talking about?

Comment: Certain steps aren't invertible: $x = y \implies x^2 = y^2$, but $x^2 = y^2$ doesn't imply that $x = y$. It's a failure of certain functions being [injective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function‎).

Answer (score 1):

When we solve logarithmic equations, we use properties of logarithms that hold only and only for positive numbers. But in an equation, we may not know ahead of time the sign of a variable, and that's where extraneous solutions come from.